# Map Fragment Z-index Not Right

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, z-index

I am trying to create something similar to Google Maps in that I have a sliding panel that slides up over a MapFragment and I want to put a StreetView preview in the SlidingUpPanel like this.

[image: Google Maps Screenshot]

The problem is when I try to do this the StreetView Fragment in the SlidingUpPanel appears to slide behind the MapFragment whilst the SlidingUpPanel slides in front. I've read about similar things happening with the Navigation Drawer and a MapFragment but none of the workarounds such as putting in an invisible view over the map worked for this.

[image: My App Screenshot]

So as you can see the StreetView Fragment should go all way to the bottom of the slide menu but it's being covered by the MapFragment.

Below you can see the XML used for the SlidingUpPanel

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
            xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            sothree:panelHeight="70dp"
            sothree:fadeColor="#00FFFFFF">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/clicktext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="123 Hollywood"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Confirmed"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#888888"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/streetview" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Is this a problem with Google Maps or OpenGL or am I doing something wrong? Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case you havent solved it yet, theres exactly the same question (with solution) on the issues page

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/issues/2